# Python opencv extract squares

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, edge-detection, canny-operator

Given an input image like this I am trying to extract larger squares outlined by darker lines.

[image]

I first tried to find lines and intersection using Hough Lines. After applying Canny edge detector I get this:
[image]

Aplying HoughLinesP on the edges results in something I did not expect:
[image]

I also tried to directly detect contours on the edges produced by Canny edge detector.

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0]
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.01*peri, True)
```

However, I get the error:

```
error: /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:237: error: (-215) count >= 0 && (depth == 5 || depth == 4) in function arcLength
```

Some googling suggest that the error appears when input image is not binary, however, the output of Canny edge detector is a binary image.

Comment: Did you try to first increase the contrast of the original image before the threshold detection?

Comment: @Asterisk,  as @SvenKrüger suggested, maybe try to filter high frequencies before using `Canny`